# Android Dialog - Replace buttons on button click within the dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-button

I am trying to display a dialog with two buttons - 1) *Not Now* 2) *Set Up Now*.

When I click the *Not Now* button in the dialog, I want to display two more buttons - A) Show Me Later B) Don't Show Again and add onclick listeners on these buttons as well. Is there a way to achieve this? Thank you.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    // On Button click show new buttons in the dialog
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Show Me Later", null //Add onClickListener);
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Don't Show Again", null // Add onClickListener);

                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    //No button clicked
                    break;
            }
        }
    };


    builder.setMessage("Update Feature").setPositiveButton("Not Now", dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Set Up Now", dialogClickListener).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

AlertDialog (and dialog in general among all UI systems) typically don't change their buttons after initially presented.  So I don't imagine it's a good idea to try it like that.

Instead, close the first dialog and present a second dialog with the second set of options you would like the user to choose.  That makes it clear they are making a second choice which is different than the first.

Comment: Thank you, Doug. Is there a way to keep the current dialog in the background in disabled mode and display a new dialog with just two buttons on the top?

Comment: I suppose you could pop a new dialog on top of the first one, but why would you want to do that?